# why after pushing items in array inside the function shows empty array outside that function in node.js(mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```js
/*Made an array of name favFruit which will store the object id of fruit collection in database*/
var favFruit = [];

Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
      //console.log(fruit._id);
      favFruit.push(fruit._id);

    });
  }
  // logging the array inside the function print all the id's correctly. 
  console.log(favFruit);
});

// logging the array outside the function prints two square brackets("[]") only.
console.log(favFruit);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop is works as async, so log in loop is works fine but log in end of code will show you empty loop,

you can use for loop to match your current code,
as per my understanding, below is the execution flow,
line - 106
line - 109
line - 117
lne - 110

you can log new Date() to check time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).